# Block Naming Issue

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I used Theme Developer module to find the candidate name for a block that I'm using and it gives me this candidate name: block__menu_block__1 But it doesn't take action when I name as block--menu-block-1.tpl.php . I've tried several other variations to no avail, and I have cleared my cache.  What would I name this block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the template suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

It should be: block--menu-block--1.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

When translating from a suggestion to a template filename, Drupal replaces every underscore with an hyphen; in this case, "block__menu_block__1" becomes "block--menu-block-−1.tpl.php" (there is a hyphen more than you used).

The code that converts underscores in hyphens is in [drupal_find_theme_templates()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/drupal_find_theme_templates/7).

```
if (!isset($info['base hook']) && !empty($pattern)) {
  // Transform _ in pattern to - to match file naming scheme
  // for the purposes of searching.
  $pattern = strtr($pattern, '_', '-');
  // …
}
```